# Grid lines don't look the same in D3?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to apple grid lines to my graph using D3.js
I have a problem as it looks like it has different opacity or color on my graph. I don't understand why, how can I fix this?

http://puu.sh/jMFaP/5bb9b8e622.png

**EDIT**

New picture to make it easier to see the problem:

http://puu.sh/jMGSs/51f324fede.png

This is the code I use to apply grid lines:

JS:

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickValues(createTickValuesArray(arr.length))
        .tickFormat(formatAxis)
        .innerTickSize(-height+100)
        .outerTickSize(0)
        .tickPadding(0);

SVG.select(".x.axis").transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*1000)
        .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .style("font-size", AXIS_FONTSIZE)
            .style("font-family", "helvetica")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "rotate(" + AXIS_ROTATION + ")" 
            });

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(yScale)
        .orient("left")
        .innerTickSize(-width+40)
        .outerTickSize(2)
        .tickPadding(0);

SVG.select(".y.axis").transition().duration(ANIMATION_TIME_MODIFIER*1500).call(yAxis)
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("font-size", AXIS_FONTSIZE)
        .style("font-family", "helvetica");
```

CSS:

```
.axis path,
  .axis line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
  }

  .tick line{
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
```

Comment: A live demo would be much more helpful than attaching static PNGs. The generated SVG's structure might as well hold some valuable hints.

Comment: Yes of course, here's a link: http://servers.binf.ku.dk/fantom5/?gene=IL3RA&dataset=promoter&tree=Primary%20Cells

Comment: looking at your SVG some of your axis tick lines have inline styles (style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(221, 221, 221);"), some don't. This probably accounts for the different appearance. Though it's not clear from the code posted above how this is happening.

Comment: Looks great by the way but, can't see any problem... I assume it's already fixed?

Comment: If your solution provides any interesting insights, please consider posting an answer to share the knowledge with the rest of us.

Comment: I fixed it somehow, although I do not know if it is the correct way. I can say that it works now though. I will provide an answer in this week when I get back on my work computer. :-)